# Using Global Variables in Classes which are exported in express.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, class, export

Here is model file for product

```
const products=[];

module.exports = class Product{
    constructor(t) {
        this.title =t;
    }
    save(){
        products.push(this)
        console.log(products)
    }
    static fetchAll(){
        console.log(products)
        return products;
    }

}
```

This is my controller file

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

exports.getAddProduct=(req, res, next) => {
    res.render('add-product',{
    pageTitle:'Add Product',
    path:'/admin/add-product',
    productCSS:true,
    activeAddProduct:true,
    formsCSS:true,
})
};

exports.postAddProduct=(req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product(req.body.title);
    product.save();
    res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    const products  = Product.fetchAll();
    res.render('shop',{
        prods:products,
        pageTitle :'Shop',
        path:'/',
        hasProducts:products.length>0,
        productCSS:true,
        activeShop:true
    });
    
  }
```

My concern is we are accessing a variable of another file in this file how is that Possible is it possible for static functions only or normal functions as well.  IN ONE LINE PROBLEM HOW DOES OBJECT OF A CLASS KNOWS ABOUT VARIABLES IN ANOTHER FILE

i expected to see some reference error

Comment: Because instances of a class are connected to the prototype of Product from the models file, and in turn that prototype has the variable `products` in scope. This is not good though, you generally never want to be mutating some var in the global scope from a class, as it implies that the code is incorrectly encapsulated. But it doesn't break the rules of JS. Other languages don't have module scope in the same way which is why you might be confused. Code outside of the class is executed as soon as the file is loaded and its in scope to everything else.